# Is it possible to buy a PvP-only account in Guild Wars?

Tags: guild-wars

Is it possible to buy a PvP-only account in Guild Wars? What is the official price?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.  The PVP Access Kit sells for $19.99 USD on [the PlayNC Store](https://secure.ncsoft.com/cgi-bin/Store.pl?dnv=4031614147&action=viewItem&item_id=61).

Buying the skill unlock packs and the PVP item unlock pack will cost extra, of course.

Comment: yes but I must buy the game before?

Comment: @Dran Dane - No.  The PVP access kit gives you access to the PVP areas of the game, without having to actually purchase a retail version of the game.  More information can be found on the [Guild Wars Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/PvP_Access_Kit).

Comment: For clarity's sake: You don't have to buy item/skill unlock packs - you can unlock them simply by playing PVP.